# DNS server's not working in subnet

Tags: fedora, dns, dnsmasq

I have installed two virtual machines on my PC - Fedora Server and Fedora Live Workstation. Fedora Server has two network interfaces - one configured as NAT interface but other one -  for working in internal network named LAN1 (10.10.2.0/24 in my case). Fedora Workstation has one network interface for working in LAN1. I have configured all network interfaces.

[image]

The problem is that I can run *ping*, *nslookup*, *yum update* commands from server but only *ping* (I can ping ip addresses from other networks as well) from workstation. I guess it's because of wrongly configured nameservers or DNS settings.

I tried different methods to solve this but nothing worked for me. Any ideas? Please leave a comment if any information from my configuration files is necessary.

Im using VirtualBox. Fedora Servers NAT network interface is configured as DHCP client (IP address is assigned automatically) but Fedora Servers LAN1 interface uses static IP - 10.10.2.1. Fedora Workstation LAN1 interface uses a static IP from 10.10.2.0/24 subnet.

Comment: sorry just to be clear you can run ping, nslookup, etc or you can not?

Comment: Side question, what app did you draw that diagram in?

Comment: I can run all the commands from Fedora Server, but from workstation I can only run ping.

Comment: @slm gliffy online soft

Comment: Fedora server is a very heavy weight distro for a just DNS. There are way lighter alternatives tailored specifically for being network appliances, which you may want to look into. Also keep in mind that Fedora is a test branch of Redhat and all Fedora users are guinea pigs for them, so do not expect production robustness, while dedicated router/dns distros are production oriented.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default gw in your WS:

```
route add default gw 10.10.2.1
```

Then :

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: The last record is Google's public DNS, what is that for here?